# What means "do this in one pass"?

Tags: python, logic

I have started in Daily Code logic problems and received the first one, an very easy, but I dont understand what "do this in one pass" means. Its do that in just one line? If yes, how thats possible in this problem?
Thats the question and my code:

```
##Good morning! Here's your coding interview problem for today.
##This problem was recently asked by Google.
##Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
##For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.
##Bonus: Can you do this in one pass?
def equivalent_sum(n,list_of_n):
  for x in list_of_n:
    for y in list_of_n:
      boolean = False
      if x != y:
        if x + y == n:
          boolean = True
        print("{} + {} {}".format(x,y,boolean))
l_of_numbers = [2,3,7,10,13,17,21]
equivalent_sum(20,l_of_numbers)
```

Comment: "One pass" means "iterate over the list once".  But your solution iterates over the list many times.

Comment: "Do this in one pass" likely means "use only one for loop" in this context.

Comment: one pas ==> O(n) time complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one pas ==> O(n) time complexity

you will iterate over the list once:

```
passed_nums = set() 
numbers = [2,3,7,10,13,17,21] 
k = 17 

def equivalent_sum(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
       diff = k - num
       if diff in passed_nums:
           return True
       passed_nums.add(num)
    return False

equivalent_sum(numbers)
```

or you can use:

```
num_set = set(numbers)
any(k - e in num_set for e in numbers)
```

build in functions are faster since they run on C code